# WCF Invalid URL when sending a HTTP post from Android

Tags: android, wcf

um trying to upload a photo from HTTP post to a WCF service endpoint. My URL is look like this .

```
 http://ankit-tobosig.org:85/Attachment.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...
```

This is my android code to execute the Httppost and there s nothing wrong it till I use the encoded string as shown above and it returns invalid url.

```
     try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.url);

        // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (httpResponse != null) {
            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                result = true;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        String xlg = e.toString();
        String mld = xlg;
    }
    return result;
```

This is my WCF endpoint declaration to accept this http post.

```
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate =    "attachment/{jobNumber}/{documentType}/{documentFilePath}/{DocumentFileName}/{encodedImage}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public bool InsertAttachment(String jobNumber, String documentType,
        String documentFilePath, String documentFileName,
         String encodedImage = null)
    {
        return newServeiceBO().InsertAttachment(
            jobNumber, documentType, documentFilePath,
            documentFileName, encodedImage);
    }
    #endregion
```

this is my web.config file

```
   <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="20480" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"  />
```

```
  <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />

  </security>
```

and the service url starts from http://ankit-tobosig.org:85/Attachment.svc/mdt/attachment/

and the end point declaration has no errors. I may use a wrong approach to upload an image from Android to WCF service and Image was compressed to 1%. I'll be grateful if any one guide me to overcome this 'INVALID URL error'. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're using `POST` but you're actually passing the uploaded-image data on the Url. also, your Url starts with `Attachment.svc/mdt`, why the `mdt` if `UriTemplate` doesn't require it?

Comment: Your Url doesn't respond.

Comment: I cannot post the actual URL . Sorry

Comment: It is possible to pass data over the Url, but that's more common when using `GET` method and not `POST`. most people choosing `POST` when they actually need to post large amounts of data to the server (like file uploads), you could also have problems with the `maxUrlLength` configuration since your Url may exceed this limit for large images.

Comment: Also, i still don't see any mention of the `mdt` prefix in your code/configuration. why are you using it?

Comment: <endpoint
          contract="XXXXX.YYYYYYYYYYY"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          behaviorConfiguration="WebHttp"
          address="mdt">
        </endpoint>

Comment: Did you try to prefix the address with a slash '/'? <endpoint contract="XXXXX.YYYYYYYYYYY" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttp" address="/mdt"> </endpoint>